# Change a string keeping some text as it is using sed

Tags: command-line, sed

I have got another problem here with SED. I wanna add some text to a string but with out changing a particular word which varies with every line. Or wrap a code on a string keeping it as it is.

Example :
FROM

```
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">COAT. how are you.
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">MONEY.Where are you.
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">FOOD.what are you.
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">CAR.which are you.
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">QUALITY.When are you.
```

TO

```
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">COAT.</b>how are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">MONEY.</b>Where are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">FOOD.</b>what are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">CAR.</b>which are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">QUALITY.</b>When are you.
```

Again thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: You want to add before how, where, what, which, when?

Comment: No i want to add after the dot "."

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: Is there any problem if we have more dots in a line? just going to give it a try, Thanks

Comment: '<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">COAT.</b>hg;kjhkh;kjnkjh
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">MONEY.</b>kjhkjgkjbkj
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">FOOD.</b>jhgkjhkjh
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">CAR.</b>kjblkjbkjb
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">QUALITY.</b>kjbhkjbjhb' No <b> at beginning.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed 's/\./\0<\/b>/g' < FileName`

It finds all occurances of "." and replaces it with "."

`sed 's/\.$/\0<\/b>/' < FileName`

It finds the occurances of "." at the end of line and replaces it with "."

`(sed 's/\.$/\0<\/b>/' | sed 's/^/\0<b>/') < FileName`

It finds the occurances of "." at the end of line and replaces it with "." and appends "" at the beginning

Comment: Sorry but there are other words and its not the end i am going to change the question a bit sorry for trouble.

Comment: Ya i saw it is appending </b> after the end "." not at the first dot. I mean to say i want to append it after the first "." and not any other in that line. Yet again changing my question a bit again.

Comment: Got it bro just removed the "$" from the first command and it is working fine. Answer : `(sed 's/\./\0<\/b>/' | sed 's/^/\0<b>/')`